# How to change a value of an object and push the object back to its array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
arr: [
  {
    id: '1',
    dataX: ''
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    dataX: ''
  }
]
```

I want to loop through each object and assign them a new value for dataX. The new value can be fetched like this

```
_.each(arr, el => {
  if (el.id === target.id) {
    console.log(target.x)
    // => new value that should be assigned to the corresponding object
  }
```

Now, how can I push that new `x` value into the corresponding object (or push the new object to the corresponding position)? Say, if `el.id === 1`, push the new `x` to the `dataX` of the object with `id` 1?

(Lodash solutions are welcomed.)

Comment: What you have a is an array of objects, not JSON. Also, it seems to be as simple as `el.dataX = target.x;`.

Comment: @Felix Kling I can't do that, because `arr` won't update.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information. Objects are mutable by default. Please provide an example that reproduces the issue you have.

Comment: object in array will update... sounds like you expect something else to update at same time. Issue is not clear at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash be gone! :D

```
var json = [
  { id: '1', dataX: '' },
  { id: '2', dataX: '' }
]
var target = {id: '2', x: 'X GONE GIVE IT TO YA!'} // Dummy data

// Note: map() returns a new array hence the json = json
json = json.map(item => {
  if (item.id === target.id) {
    item.dataX = target.x
  }
  return item
})

console.log(json)

// If you want to modify the original array of objects
json.forEach(item => {
  if (item.id === target.id) {
    item.dataX = target.x
  }
})

console.log(json)
```

Comment: Thanks, answer selected! (Despite of not having used Lodash.)

Comment: @alexchenco: So, the thing you said doesn't work actually does work, yes?

Comment: @Felix Kling Oh at first I thought you just wanted to do `el.dataX = target.x` without `json = json.map`. Yes, it works if you redefine `json` again.

Comment: @alexchenco: It also works fine without doing that: https://jsfiddle.net/jkw8d7aL/ . If using `.map` is the solution, then you have to update the example in your question to make it clearer why `.map` would be a solution. So far, the information you provided doesn't require `.map` as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PYDVcvYsYOqigE9MwvBU?p=preview)

```
var arr =[  {    id: '1',    dataX: ''  },  {    id: '2',    dataX: ''  }];

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);

var datas = '5';
var bonus = 'More data can be placed into the item';

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  arr[i].dataX = datas; //modifies the actual item in the array
  arr[i].dataY = bonus; //javaScript!
}

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

By addressing the actual item in the array you do not have to push it back in. It's changed. The answer above creates a new array in place of the existing one, and remaps all the items there in.

If that is the desired result then the question is poorly phrased.